# I´m having a problem with a button alignment

Tags: html, css

I was trying to have fun by making a joke with some friends and i ended up getting stuck when a button i my website wasn't aligned in the center of the page.

Where is my HTML  code:

```html
  <body>

  <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
    <br><br>
    <div class="content">


    <h1> Roderick15's Stuff</h1>
    <br><br>
      <br><br>

    <button onclick="window.location.href='deathnote.php'"
    class="btn">Death Note</button>
  </body>
```

And where's my css code:

```css
   body {
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-size: 28px;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }


   .btn {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
   }

  .btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    color : white;
   }

   h1{
    text-align: center;
   }
```

I hope someone can help me getting rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the float left
and change the margin to "0 auto" if you want to center the button

```
   .btn {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        background-color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        line-height: 50px;
        }
```

Comment: I tried with the code you gave me and it seems to do exactly the same. The real problem is that when i minimize the window the button goes to the left and doesn't stay in the middle as i wanted to.

Comment: No problem. But i don't know why but when i refresh my page i can't see a single alteration in the design or the alignment of the button. Maybe it's becuse of my "code reader". If the problem is the "code reader" i will let you know that i use "WAMP server"  <http://www.wampserver.com/en/>

Answer (score 1):

To be able to center an element horizontally you can use "margin: auto"
This requires the object to have a certain width, (for example "width: 150px;")

In your example, you use "float left", which causes the element to stick to the left of the screen in this case.

Removing "float: left;" and "margin-right: 5px;"
and adding

```
"width: 150px;"
"margin: auto;"
```

Should do the trick.

So that the .btn class looks like this;

```
.btn {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I recommend W3 schools if you need any more info.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: So first of all i would like to thank you for the help but it seems that the code you gave didn't change anything in the alignment of the button. Maybe it's becuse of my "code reader". If the problem is the "code reader" i will let you know that i use "WAMP server" <wampserver.com/en> . I aldeady knew <www.w3schools.com> but i've forgotten to check if there was something that i migth help me think of a solution.  Anyway thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: No problem! 
I also forgot to mention to remove the "margin-right:5px". 
My answer may not have been very clear so I made some changes. 
Feel free to contact me if you need any help.

Comment: I've tried again your code and  it worked. Thank you.